# Remove last separator from print statement

Tags: java, printing, separator

Here's a method for sorting an integer array. How can I remove the last separator form the output?

```
public void Sort(int[] sort) {
        for (int a:sort) {
            System.out.print(a+ ", ");
        }
    }
```

Output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
```

Desired Output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, a very clean solution is using the new [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class. This class was designed to join Strings together with a custom separator, and possibly with a prefix / suffix. With this class, you don't need to worry about deleting the last separator as you do in your snippet.

```
public void sort(int[] sort) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (int a : sort) {
        sj.add(String.valueOf(a));
    }
    System.out.println(sj.toString());
}
```

You could also drop the `for` loop and use Streams instead:

```
String str = Arrays.stream(sort).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(joining(","));
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options:

```
public void Sort(int[] sort) {
  for (int i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(sort[i]);
     if (i < sort.length - 1) {
       // not the last element. Add separator
       System.out.print(" ,");  
     }
  }
}
```

Another way:

```
public void Sort(int[] sort) {
  String output = Arrays.toString(sort);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output).substring(1, output.length-1));
}
```

Comment: First option is great. With the second option I get the error: `The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (String)`, also shouldn't it be `output.length()` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can fix the problem just try it.

```
public static void sort(int[] sort) {
    for (int a:sort) {
        if(a==sort[sort.length-1])
            System.out.println(a);
        else
            System.out.print(a+ ", ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Sort(int[] sort) {
     int i = 1;
     String str = Arrays.toString(sort);

     str = str.substring(i,str.length()-1);
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I like it, but how can i format this? ie. remove the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You may use a StringBuilder as follows:

```
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    int[] sort = {1,2,3,4,5,7,89,4,9,6,11,23,178,29};
    for(int i : sort) sb.append(i+", ");
    if(sb.length()>2)       sb.delete(sb.length()-2, sb.length());
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

EDIT: This is not the sorting algorythm. This is just an example of how you can present it without the last comma.

Comment: It’s probably better not to add the comma in the first place instead of adding it then removing it.

Comment: @bfontaine indeed, not saying this is the best way to. It is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Easily can do like below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(i < sort.length-1 ?sort[i]+", " : sort[i]+"");
    }
```